# Understanding overcounting and adjustment for it

Tags: probability

I don't understand where they get factor of overcounting from. The sentence:

> to account for the fact that the S’s can be permuted among themselves
> in any way

This sentence does not explain anything to me, I don't understand why does it mean that we overcounted by factor of 3!

[image]

Or let's take

> Consider a group of four people
>
> How many ways are there to break the
> people into two teams of two?

One of the solutions:

> there are 6 ways to choose one team. This overcounts by a factor of 2,
> since picking 1 and 2 to be a team is equivalent to picking 3 and 4 to be a team. So
> again the answer is 6/2 = 3.

How do I know it overcounts by factor of 2? Why are factors of overcounting pulled from thin air?
Is it really intuitive and everyone except me understands it?

These are:
Introduction to Probability, Second Edition (Joseph K. Blitzstein, Jessica Hwang)
Pages 15 and 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first, the reason is simple: no matter how you permute the S's among themselves, the word appears the same. For instance, here are six "duplicate" permutations, where the S's have been made distinct by color.

[image]

Each triplet of S's can be shuffled around, but the same word is formed. Hence, for the complete collection, $1/3!=1/6$ of them are filled with duplicates formed by the S's not *really* being distinct.

---

For your other one, consider: I have four people. I want teams of two.

I pick one team of two, and hence have two people remaining -- *the choice for the final team has been forced by the first one.*

If I pick Persons $1$ and $2$ for the team, then $3$ and $4$ are on the other team. Conversely, if I pick $3$ and $4$ for the team, then the other team is $1$ and $2$.

Any picking of teams has a duplicate situation like this and, under the assumption the teams are fundamentally identical, that means half of the possible teams counted in that naive way are really just duplicates.